# Angular mapping fields from an array while converting only numbers to strings?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a model and need to map this json that is filtered from another json object below to the model. I want to convert all the number values to strings but keep bool values intact. How can that be done dynamically?

```
 var users = [{
            "firstName": "john",
            "middleName": null,
            "lastName": "doe",
            "registrationNumber": 334,
            "isOld": true
        },
        {
            "firstName": "paul",
            "middleName": null,
            "lastName": "dean",
            "registrationNumber": 123,
            "isOld": true

        },
        {
            "firstName": "andrew",
            "middleName": null,
            "lastName": "mac",
            "registrationNumber": 132,
            "isOld": true
        }
    ]
```

This maps the filtered data to my model however the number fields are still numeric and I need them as strings. Remember this is dynamic data so I may not have numbers.

```
this.model = {};
    users.map(item => this.model[item.key] = item.value);
```

Comment: i think this will fix you up...  item.value.toString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
let users = [{
    "firstName": "john",
    "middleName": null,
    "lastName": "doe",
    "registrationNumber": 334,
    "isOld": true
  },
  {
    "firstName": "paul",
    "middleName": null,
    "lastName": "dean",
    "registrationNumber": 123,
    "isOld": true

  },
  {
    "firstName": "andrew",
    "middleName": null,
    "lastName": "mac",
    "registrationNumber": 132,
    "isOld": true
  }
];

let arr=users.map(user =>{
 Object.keys(user).forEach((prop) =>{
  if (typeof user[prop] == "number") 
      user[prop] = String(user[prop])
  });
  return user;
});
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Just my two cents: it's a bad practice to modify the properties of the `object` you are iterating in the `Array#map`. To avoid this, instead of `forEach`, you could use `reduce`: `users.map(user => {
  return Object.keys(user).reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
    const propertyValue = user[currentValue];
    previousValue[currentValue] = typeof propertyValue === 'number' ? propertyValue.toString() : propertyValue;

    return previousValue;
  }, {});
});`